# c++ filesystem::path imprimir caracteres especiales

Tags: c++, filesystem, c++17

Estoy realizando un programa que recorre todos los directorios y los imprime por consola, haciendo uso de la librería Filesystem c++17, el problema es que al iterar sobre un archivo que contenga en su nombre algún carácter extraño (acentos por ejemplo) y tratar de imprimirlo mediante un `std::cout` o al tratar de meterlo en un string  salta un error. El código que falla es el siguiente:

```
void recorrer(const fs::path& path)
{

    for (fs::directory_entry const& pathFile : fs::directory_iterator(path, fs::directory_options::skip_permission_denied))
    {
        std::string micadena = pathFile.path().string();  //FALLA
        std::cout << micadena << '\n';
    }
}
```

El error:

Excepción no controlada en 0x75924662 en xxxxx.exe: excepción de Microsoft C++: std::system_error en la ubicación de memoria 0x002AF148.

Creo que debe tratarse de un error de codificación, pero ando un poco perdido en este tema.

Estoy utilizando el IDE de VS con la última versión del compilador y caracteres multibyte. En cuanto a esto entiendo que cuando seleccionas el modo en la configuración de VS Unicode se refiere a UTF-8 y multibye a UTF-16 es esto correcto?

Answer (score 2):

Para tratar con codificaciones no ASCII debes usar `std::wcout` y `std::wstring`

```
void recorrer(const fs::path& path)
{

    for (fs::directory_entry const& pathFile : fs::directory_iterator(path, fs::directory_options::skip_permission_denied))
    {
        std::wstring micadena = pathFile.path().wstring();
        std::wcout << micadena << '\n';
    }
}
```

Nota que tienes [otras opciones](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/string) para recuperar el path.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta, pero sigo teniendo el mismo problema a la hora de imprimir las rutas, la diferencia ahora es que usando Unicode (wstring()) cuando esta listando los directorios si encuentra una ruta con algún carácter extraño, deja de imprimir, aunque el código no devuelve errores